# In zc.buildout, how do I install egg A, then install egg B which needs egg A to install correctly?

Tags: python, cython, buildout, pymssql

Specifically, here's the situation I'm running into:

I am using zc.buildout to install an application which requires pymssql. Pymssql requires Cython in order to install properly. However, I would like to not modify my running environment, so I would like to do something like:

1. Install Cython
2. Load Cython into buildout
3. Install Pymssql.

I thought Buildout did this already, but it looks more like it checks the setup.cfg to ensure that anything that explicitly stated as necessary is installed. Current my buildout looks like:

```
[buildout]
  parts = required-eggs
  ...

[required-eggs]
  eggs = Cython
         pymssql
```

Cython installs fine. Unfortunately pymssql does not:

```
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1101, in build_and_install
self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1090,  in run_setup
run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 29, in run_setup
lambda: execfile(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 70, in run
return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 31, in <lambda>
{'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 41, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Cython.Distutils
```

Thus, I think that Cython is installed as an egg, but is not loaded into the python process that is running buildout. Is there some configuration in buildout that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pymssql` package alreade declares the `Cython` egg as a `setup_requires` dependency, but doesn't give `distutils` time to install it. Simply listing them in `setup_requires` but still attempting to import them at module scope (as `pymssql` does) is not enough.

The `setup.py` module would have to be restructured to not import the `Cython` dependency until the `setup_requires` line has been parsed and the dependencies listed there have been made available. Basically, it needs to define it's own `build_cmd` class that, when instantiated, imports the `Cython` dependency and wraps that class at that time, and not before.

It may be that you could create a custom buildout recipe that uses `Cython` as a dependency that then can install the `pymssql` dependency with `Cython` installed by buildout as it executes your recipe, but that is a plaster on this wound that `pymssql` should deal with, really.

Comment: Thank you for that answer, It helps me better understand what is actually going on! I guess I'll just include a pre-compiled pymssql and deal with the issues with that.